# Python3 string formatting with multiple parameters

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm writing to a text file where i want a field of a formatted string to be left-justified AND have 2-digit float precision.

Sample input (does not work):

```
txt = "We have {:.2f <8} chickens."
print(txt.format(0.123124234123412341324))
```

Desired output:

```
0.12 (left justified, with 8 spaces)
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your goal, but have you tried `{:<8.2f}`?

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Python [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), alignment specifiers (e.g. `<`) and width specifiers (e.g. `8`) must precede the floating point precision specifier (e.g. `.2`). With this criteria in mind, the correct formulation for your format string is `{:<8.2f}`:

```
txt = "We have {:<8.2f} chickens."
print(txt.format(0.123124234123412341324))
```

Output:

```
We have 0.12     chickens.
```